# EVAL: undefined function in Common LISP

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, eval, read-eval-print-loop

I am defining a simple function for power in CLISP as :

```
(defun power(B E)
  (if (= E 1)
      B
      (* B ( power (B (- E 1))))))
```

But when I try to call the function like this:

```
(power 2 6)
```

I get the following error:

> *** - EVAL: undefined function B

I tried the following code on [Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/9S8lLv) as :

```
(defun power(B E)
  (if (= E 1)
      B
      (* B ( power (B (- E 1))))))
(setq base (read))
(setq exponent (read))
(print (power(base exponent)))
```

with STDIN as

```
2
6
```

Then again, STDERR throws this error :

> *** - EVAL: undefined function BASE

Why the *argument* B or BASE isn't seen as a variable but a *function*?
Numeric values are *self-evaluative* so why this code doesn't work?

Comment: How do you write a function call? parenthesis function arg0 arg1 ... argn closing parenthesis. Right? Now what is `(B (- E 1))`? Looks to me like a function call. Just what Lisp says. But B is a variable and not a function. So Lisp complains. Rightly so.

Comment: I'm downvoting your question, because the code lacks proper indentation. Basically it has NO indentation at all. Please edit your question and format the code correctly.

Comment: `(base exponent)` that also is a function call. won't work.

Comment: How do you call a function with two arguments? Like in `(+ a b)` or `(+ (a b))`. What do you think?

Comment: @RainerJoswig : Being a LISP newbie, I was expecting downvotes already :) though I had made a stupid mistake of calling the function as f(x) instead of f x .

Comment: @Vatine yes, that one is a similar question, only the guy is getting random errors. I'll mark my question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(defun power (B E)
  (if (= E 1)
    B
    (* B (power B (- E 1)))))
```

...you can't add in "redundant" parenthesis in Lisp the way you can with some other programming languages.

Comment: That was a really silly mistake.

Comment: @RishbhSharma It is together with the dual namespace the most common beginner stumbles.